# get frequency of unique values for each group of values within a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am trying to reduce down a dataframe to get the frequency of grouped values.

Here is an example of what my dataframe (say df1) looks like -

```
col1    col2    col3
A   X1  H1
A   X1  H1
A   X1  H2
A   X2  H3
A   X2  H3
B   X1  H1
B   X2  H2
B   X2  H3
B   X2  H3
B   X3  H4
B   X4  H5
```

and the result I want to get from this ...

```
  col1 col2 col3
A   5   2   3
B   6   4   5
```

To further explain the expected result - the first column should have the frequency of the unique values in df1$col1, second column - the number of unique values for each group from df1$col1, and 3rd column the number of unique values for each group from df1$col1 as well.

So far I have this bit of code -

```
col1_count<-df1 %>% count(col1)
col2_count<-df1 %>% count(col1,col2)
col3_count<-df1 %>% count(col1,col2,col3)

merged_col1_col2<-full_join(col1_count,col2_count)
```

Unfortunately it's not giving me what I need and am kind of confused how to go from here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  summarise(col1 = n(),
            across(col2:col3, n_distinct), .by = col1)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
   col1  col2  col3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     5     2     3
2     6     4     5
```

And if you want to keep the original group values, make a copy before summarising:

```
df1 |> 
  mutate(grp = col1) |> 
  summarise(col1 = n(),
            across(col2:col3, n_distinct), .by = grp)

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  grp    col1  col2  col3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         5     2     3
2 B         6     4     5
```